Unable to Log In as Root Despite Correct Password: Potential Issues and Solutions
I'm encountering an issue when trying to log in as the root user on my Linux system. Even though I am entering the correct password, I am unable to access the system. I’ve double-checked the password and ensured it is correct, but the login attempt still fails.

DO you use ssh or you try via console?

no . i will try now

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

so exactly after entering the password of root it again showing me the login page . means i need to enter my login details again and its happening again again.

Does your system allow root login, or is it only allowing root access using "sudo su -" from your normal login userid?

from a normal user i can login to root .

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

So, no root login, and not on the sudoers file?
You can to boot from a live CD  and mount the root filsystem on your live CD Linux and try to find the reason why you do not have root access. like, try to add your userid to the sudoers file or check the /etc/passwd root entry (like: does it has a correct shell program configured).
